# Assign integers from dictionary values to characters of a string

Tags: javascript, swift

`indices` and `for value in` nicely gives me the loop I'm looking for however I need to go a step further and assign the values of the dictionary to the matching characters of the string then perform calculation for score.

I'd like to know the most Swifty way to accomplish this. Is this possible using `map`? `let curChar = n.map({ print($0) })`.

The other issue is that Javascript lets you used heterogeneous dictionaries of type easily but with Swift we need to match types.

```
var dict: [String:Any] = ["a":1, "j":1, "s":1, "b":2, "k":2,"r":9/*...*/]

let n = "lighthouse"
var nScore = 0

for i in n.indices[n.startIndex..<n.endIndex] {
let curChar = n[i]
var curVal = dict[curChar] 
nScore = nScore + curVal
```

The original Javascript block.

```
var dict = {A:1, J:1, S:1, B:2, K:2, T:2...};
var n = "lighthouse";
var nScore = 0;

for( var i = 0; i < n.length; i++ );
{
    var curChar = n.charAt( i );
    var curVal = dict[ curChar ];
    nScore = nScore + curVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n[i]` is of type `Character`, so that should be the key type
of the dictionary instead of `String`. The value type should be `Int`:

```
let dict: [Character: Int] = ["a": 1, "j": 1, "s": 1, "b": 2, "k": 2, "r": 9 /* ... */]
```

You also have to define a "default value" which is used as score
for characters not found in the dictionary, this can be done
with the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
let n = "lighthouse"
var nScore = 0

for i in n.indices[n.startIndex..<n.endIndex] {
    let curChar = n[i]
    let curVal = dict[curChar] ?? 0
    nScore = nScore + curVal
}
```

Or simpler, by enumerating the characters of the string directly:

```
for c in n {
    let curVal = dict[c] ?? 0
    nScore = nScore + curVal
}
```

Even shorter with [`reduce()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce):

```
let n = "lighthouse"
let nScore = n.reduce(0) { (score, c) in
    score + (dict[c] ?? 0)
}
```

which can be written more compactly using "shorthand parameters":

```
let n = "lighthouse"
let nScore = n.reduce(0) { $0 + (dict[$1] ?? 0) }
```

If it you have *full control* over the possible characters which can
occur in the input string, and it is *guaranteed(!)* the dictionary
defines values for all of them  then you can force-unwrap the dictionary lookup, for example

```
let n = "lighthouse"
let nScore = n.reduce(0) { $0 + dict[$1]! }
```

But this will *crash* at runtime if a character is not found.

---

If you define a function

```
func numericScore(_ str: String) -> Int {
    return str.reduce(0) { $0 + (dict[$1] ?? 0) }
}
```

then you can easily apply it to a single string

```
let nScore = numericScore("lighthouse")
```

or map it over an array of strings

```
let words = ["lighthouse", "motorcycle"]
let scores = words.map(numericScore)
```

or compute the total score for an array of strings (using `reduce` again):

```
let words = ["lighthouse", "motorcycle"]
let totalScore = words.reduce(0) { $0 + numericScore($1) }

// Alternatively in two steps:

let scores = words.map(numericScore)
let totalScores = scores.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: @tymac: There are about 136,000 Unicode characters, did you define a score for all of them? What if the input string is `" "`? – But I have added an alternative for the case that you have full control over the possible input.

Comment: Thank you sir. It works mighty splendidly So basically I just messed up with the dictionary type. Makes me feel a whole lot better knowing that my actual block was ok. My first time ever using a type of `[Character : Int]`. Your alternative versions are nice. I ended up using the second one because it's both more readable for others and shorter than the first one. See you around‍♂️

Comment: If there were two strings i.e. `"lighthouse"` and `"motorcycle"` and I decided to make it one array with those two words so that I could get a score for both words simultaneously would I still use `indices`? Let me know if that requires a new question. Thanks.

Comment: @tymac: See updated answer. – It that does not satisfy your needs, a new question might be better.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. I really appreciate that bonus.