# Sum integers from a key value until there is one-digit

Tags: swift

I need a function that both reduces integers to a single digit and accepts strings. Variants using reduce would also be appreciated.

```
let dict: [Character:Int] = ["a": 1, "j":1, "s":1, "b":2, "k":2, "t":2, "c":3, "l":3, "u":3, "d":4, "m":4, "v":4, "e":5, "n":5, "w":5, "f":6, "o":6, "x":6, "g":7, "p":7, "y":7, "h":8, "q":8, "z":8, "i":9, "r":9]
```

This function accepts strings and reduces by summing, but does not reduce to a single digit.

```
func f1(_ str: String) -> Int {
return str.reduce(0) { $0 + (dict[$1] ?? 0) }
}
f1("lighthouse") //52
```

This function reduces to a single digit but does not accepts strings.

```
func f2(_ n: Int) -> Int {
return (1 + ((n-1) % 9))
}
f2(52) //7
```

Comment: Can you post your whole dictionary values? Where is your `x` declared and what is its value? Is it supposed to be dict?

Comment: So, combine the functions then? As in, call the second one in the first one.

Comment: Can't you just overload the function?  It has different argument types so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: `return (1 + ((str.reduce(0) { $0 + (dict[$1] ?? 0) }-1) % 9)) `

Comment: you can remove some parentheses `return 1 + (str.reduce(0) {$0 + (dict[$1] ?? 0)} - 1) % 9`

Comment: If you want a single function to handle both types, you'll have to 1) Use `Any` (ewww), 2) Make a protocol, 3) Accept both types as optional and default them to nil.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What's your use case?

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks Leo. It's perfect. Could you please write it as an answer so I can mark it correct. That would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to combine your both methods in the return statement:

```
return 1 + (str.reduce(0) {$0 + (dict[$1] ?? 0)} - 1) % 9
```

Comment: Hi. I also "reversed engineered" your answer to figure out how to write it using the regular Swift for in loop version without `reduce()` and shorthand. It took me three tries I wrote another answer just to have it for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that converts a string into a single digit Int.

**Input: "9l231ffi1j"**

```
func f1(_ str: String) -> Int {
    return str.reduce(0) { $0 + ((Int(String($1)) ?? dict[$1]) ?? 0) }
}

func f3(_ input : String) -> Int {
    return f2(f1(input))
}
f3("lighthouse") //7

f3("9l231ffi1j") //5
```

Comment: Because `Any` should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: That's not true, there are some perfectly valid cases in where Any or AnyObject can be used.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding the question. The OP wants one function that takes a string and returns a single digit sum. Leo posted the answer in the comments.

Comment: @rmaddy ah, that makes more sense, updated my answer.

Comment: You should remove all of the initial answer and the new part doesn't really match the OP's original code.

Comment: @rmaddy I thought the OP wanted something that converts strings like "hello123" into a single digit int. Leo's comment doesn't do that.

Comment: Hi @Pochi. Thanks for your answer. Leo's answer was the one I was looking for. I also added my own answer because it is also another version I was looking for. I was able to figure it out after I saw Leo's use of shorthand and `reduce()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Leo's answer in this question and Martin's answer in my other related [[question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494734/assign-integers-from-dictionary-values-to-characters-of-a-string) I was able to produce a standard version using Swift's for in loop without shorthand `{$0 $1}` and `reduce()`.

```
let n = "lighthouse"
var nScore = 0
for i in n.indices {
    let curChar = n[i]
    let curVal = dict[curChar, default: 0]
    nScore = 1 + (nScore + curVal - 1) % 9
}
nScore //7
```

Comment: `[n.startIndex..<n.endIndex]` is redundant  `for i in n.indices {` and Swift 4 you can assign a default value to dictionary subscript `x[curChar, default: 0]`

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.